# other ways of saying "getting/coming" out of poverty?

Tags: word-request

What are other ways of saying "getting/coming" out of poverty? More formal and concise?

I want to express the idea that progress in economy help people "come out of poverty" after a severe economic downturn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual phrase I've seen is "escaping poverty."